# The number of processes in the system run queue

Tags: php

Что такое

> the number of processes in the system run queue

Точнее, как это можно использовать для оценки загруженности системы?
Английский я знаю, переводить не нужно. Но мне кажется, это попугаи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таки да, это попугаи, если нам незвестны характеристики сервера.
Однако, если мы имеем некоторый промежуток времени, мы можем следить за динамикой, а это уже ккое-что.

Если эта очередь начинает расти, это может означать либо что что-то отвалилось, либо идет атака, либо просто что сервер перестал справляться с наплывом посетителей, в любом случае стоит сообщить об этом администратору сайта.

Идеальное значение - 1. Это значит, что сервер используется рационально. Менее единицы - простаивает, более - не справляется с загрузкой.

Comment: ну как сказать, обычно на многоядерных системах LA=N, где N число ядер, всё ещё нормально.

Comment: php функция это учитывает?

Comment: Тут желательно еще посмотреть на приоритеты этих процессов.

Даже если их много, но с низким приоритетом (скажем, 19), то все нормально (базовый приоритет - 0).

Comment: @knes sys_getloadavg() ? я думаю она берет данные из /proc/loadavg там всё предельно просто.